# Как динамически задать курсор из строки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Хочу передавать в процедуру строку с запросом для курсора. Пробую сделать это так:

```
DECLARE    
  TYPE t_client_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN CLIENTS%ROWTYPE;
  v_client_cursor t_client_cursor;
  v_client CLIENTS%ROWTYPE;
  v_query_text VARCHAR2(100) := 'SELECT * FROM CLIENTS C WHERE ROWNUM < 4 ORDER BY C.CLNT_ID';
BEGIN
OPEN v_client_cursor FOR
  exec (v_query_text);
....
END;
/
```

Ругается

```
ORA-06550: Трока 8, столбец 6; 
PLS-00455: курсор 'V_CLIENT_CURSOR' нельзя использовать в команде OPEN dynamic 
SQL ORA-06550: Строка 8, столбец 1: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Но как-то ведь должно быть возможным определить курсор из строки?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA  Example 7-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
declare
  v_client_cursor sys_refcursor;
  v_query_text VARCHAR2(100) := 
          'SELECT * FROM CLIENTS C WHERE ROWNUM < 4 ORDER BY C.CLNT_ID';
begin
  open v_client_cursor for v_query_text;

  ...

  close v_client_cursor;
end;
/
```